# Using gcloud with tmux?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, tmux

I'm trying to transfer a big folder from my machine to google cloud using `gcloud compute scp`. However after a night I receive the broken pipe error message. I'm wondering if gcloud command can be used with tmux.

Comment: I see you're not super new here so you should know how this works: Test things first. Then if it doesn't work you come to Stack Overflow with the exact problem you have. Now, about your question, I see no reason why tmux would help you with your problem

Comment: Can you provide more more details ? Some error message or logs that would indicate what's the issue here ?